# Использование async/await в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Всем привет. Запутался немного в коде. Почему поток `Main` завершается до запуска этого кода ?

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Console.WriteLine("Pavel");
        });
```

Решил попробовать в `Main` приписать к вызову метода `Math1` слово `await` но тогда код вообще не компилируется. А если его убрать, то выходит , что `Main` завершился мгновенно и дело не дошло до указанного выше блока кода. Привожу весь код

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class a
{
    public async Task Meth1()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Console.WriteLine("Pavel");
        });
    }
}
class b
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a A = new a();
        await A.Meth1(); //без await сразу все завершается, с ним не компилится
    }
}
```

Почему так происходит и как решить такую ситуацию ? Я ожидаю от кода такое поведение, что при вызове `Meth1` `Main` ожидает пока в `Meth1`  выполнится лямбда

Comment: В этом и заключается суть асинхронности: вызвали асинхронный метод, и пока он выполняется, не ждём, а продолжаем работать.

Comment: @polyakov_s: Поменял заголовок, надеюсь, вы не против.

Comment: Нет конечно, наоборот ЗА. Буду рад если кому-то будет проще найти этот вопрос и увидеть Ваш ответ на него.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Обновление**. [Начиная с C# 7.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main), модификатор `async` можно использовать также и для функции `Main`. При этом неудобство, описанное ниже (отсутствует `SynchronizationContext` по умолчанию, а значит, код после `await` не будет возвращаться в исходный поток), остаётся.

---

Смотрите.

Если вы используете `async`/`await`, приложение командной строки — не лучший выбор. К сожалению, C# из коробки не поддерживает `async` для функции `Main` ([обсуждение на гитхабе](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1695), вы можете тоже отписаться, чтобы было понятно, что эта фича нужна).

Поэтому вы должны писать что-то вроде такого:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task AsyncMain(string[] args)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Console.WriteLine("Pavel");
        });
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // синхронное ожидание!
        AsyncMain(args).Wait();
    }
}
```

Другая проблема состоит в том, что в приложениях командной строки нету `SynchronizationContext`'а, который мог бы «вернуть» выполнение в начальный поток. Потому что для этого нужен в той или иной форме аналог message loop'а, а у вас его нету. Таким образом, поведение программы будет отличаться от того, что обычно бывает в WPF/WinForms: код после `await` **не будет** возвращаться в исходный поток!

Как бороться с этим? Простейший обходной путь — можно тренироваться не на приложении командной строки, а на графическом приложении.

Более хороший путь — воспользоваться существующим message loop'ом. Например, так:

```
/*
    Обвязочный код для использования async/await в консольных приложениях на C#
    Создаёт SynchronizationContext, который возвращает async-вызовы в главный поток
    (в отличие от стандартного контекста, который бы использовался в консольных приложениях)
    Идея VladD, используйте и переделывайте как хотите. Никаких гарантий, разумеется.
    Требует подключения WindowsBase.dll
*/
class Program
{
    static async Task<int> AsyncMain(string[] args)
    {
        // тут стартует ваша программа, можете пользоваться async/await
        // не забудьте про return, например:
        return 0;
    }

    [STAThread]
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = -1;
        var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                AsyncMain(args).ContinueWith(asyncMain =>
                    {
                        if (!asyncMain.IsCanceled && !asyncMain.IsFaulted)
                            result = asyncMain.Result;
                        dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
                    },
                    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            }));
        Dispatcher.Run();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ !! Буду тренироваться

Comment: Пожалуйста! Учтите, что код в конце ответа экспериментальный, если он не работает, пишите — исправим.