# Асинхронный метод: как избавиться от исключения InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, ping

Как решить эту проблему без потери производительности?

При выполнении асинхронного метода происходит ошибка: "уже выполняется асинхронный вызов. Он должен быть завершен или отменен, прежде чем можно будет вызвать этот метод".

Ошибка происходит при выполнении этого кода - при закомментированном Thread.Sleep(1000);. Соответственно, если раскомментировать - нормально выполняется.

```
var tasks = ips.Select(ipAndPort =>
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var ip = ipAndPort.Split(':')[0];
            return ping.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout);
        }).ToList();
```

Но это оборачивается потерей производительности.  ping.Dispose() тоже не помогает.

Ниже - весь код.
Класс и метод

```
public class PingSix
{
    public async static Task<List<string>> Ping(List<string> ips)
    {
        List<string> goodIps = new List<string>();
        List<string> badIps = new List<string>();
        int timeout = 1000;
        Ping ping = new Ping();

        var tasks = ips.Select(ipAndPort =>
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var ip = ipAndPort.Split(':')[0];
            return ping.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout);
        }).ToList();

        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
        {
            if (results[i].Status == IPStatus.Success)
                goodIps.Add(ips[i]);
            else
                badIps.Add(ips[i]);
        }
        return goodIps;
    }
}
```

Который вызывается в методе:

```
        static async void Example6()
    {
        var allIps = new List<string>(Properties.Resources.TextFile1.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        var goodIps = await PingSix.Ping(allIps);

        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - dt;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", "Выполнение 6 метода: ", ts);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", "Good Ips: ", goodIps.Count);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Который вызывается в главном методе:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Example6();
    }
```

Comment: Если вы пользуетесь async/await в приложении командной строки, вам наверняка пригодится [вот это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440616/10105).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если `Ping` не разрешает делать параллельные вызовы - вам надо создавать новый `Ping` для каждого вызова:

```
    var tasks = ips.Select(ipAndPort =>
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        var ip = ipAndPort.Split(':')[0];
        return ping.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout);
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: старик, ты гений!

Comment: @pontekorvo, если ответ помог - надо отметить его такой зеленой галочкой...