# Ошибка компиляции - The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method

Tags: c#, async-await

Появилась необходимость добавить асинхронный API в проект. До этого моё многопоточное программирование огграничивалось использованием `System.Threading`.
Начал разбираться с *Async/Await и TPL*. Взял простой пример из **MSDN**:

```
 async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
    {            
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();            
        Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");   
        string urlContents = await getStringTask;
        return urlContents.Length;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //ERROR:
        //The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.
        //Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its
        //return type to 'Task'.
        string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync();
    }
```

Если я правильно понял, то `await` должен заставить сработать оператор присвоения после выполнения асинхронной операции, определённой в `async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()`. Но появляется ошибка. В чём соль?

Comment: Было: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440616/10105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение может быть таким:

```
static async Task<string> AccessTheWebAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var getStringTask = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
    return getStringTask;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = AccessTheWebAsync();
    // ожидаем выполнение таски
    task.Wait();
    // получаем результат
    var urlContents = task.Result;
}
```